# Designing NoSQL data tables

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

I'm trying to wrap my head around NoSQL tables. Let's consider a simple online store schema in the SQL way:

```
Customers
----------
id
name
email

Products
----------
id
name
price

Orders
----------
id
customer_id
date_paid
orders  (will contain JSON {product_id, qty})
```

Since I think in SQL, converting this to NoSQL is going to be pretty much exactly the same.

Is this schema just fine in NoSQL for answering these questions?

- Show all/one customers
- Show all/one orders
- Show all/one products
- Show paid orders (e.g., if date_paid attribute is set)
- Show unpaid orders (e.g., if date_paid attribute is blank)
- Show customers who ordered product id
- Show orders of customer id

If not, how should it be designed?

Comment: Why are you using NoSQL for this?

Comment: @DamianW for academic purposes

Comment: Go watch all of the videos with Rick Houlihan talking about DynamoDB and NoSQL design patterns. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rick+houlihan